# Spectral sequence of non-cohomologically trivial fibration.

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, fibration

It is a well known that in case when we have $\xi: E\to B$ - a Serre fibration, with the trivial action of $\pi_1(B)$ on a fiber $F$, we have standart Atiyah - Hirzebruch spectral sequence. What we have in the case when $\pi_1(B)$ acts non-trivially? Please, give me some links to the subject.

Comment: You need local coefficients. See [the first section here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0379.pdf).

Comment: Great link, thank you very much!